# How to run an Ionic App on a Mac transferred from a PC

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

Alright so I think my question is going to be flamed for how vague it is but please hear me out.

I managed to recently get a MacBook to test apps in iOS. But I have my Ionic app developed on my Windows PC. So I thought that I would just be able to transfer the Ionic project folder over to the Mac and then run it the same way on VSCode on my MacBook. However, when I do `ionic serve`, the terminal will return this:

`[ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code -13).`

I looked up this `exit code -13` on StackOverflow already, but there doesn't seem to be much information about it. I already tried doing `ionic build` and `npm audit fix` but they don't seem to be working.

Hence, I am hoping that someone can guide me on how I can properly transfer my Ionic project from a PC to a Mac so that I can run it the same way as I run it on a PC?

The version of Ionic I'm running is 5.4.16 and Cordova is version 9.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

This is either a permission issue or a a `node_modules` issue. It's because you transfered the full project folder from another computer.

To resolve the issue, run :

```
npm rebuild
```

To clear npm cache and rebuild your modules

And :

```
chmod 755 -R /yourpath/to/node_modules
```

The error may be caused by an installation of a module which was made insudo mode

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the node_modules folder and then running `npm install`? Then trying to run the app with `ionic serve`

Comment: You may also need install ionic globally on the MacBook, seen as it's new. Run `npm install -g @ionic/cli` as well

Comment: I ran `npm install -g @ionic/cli` already prior to importing my app folder but it returned me an error which says 
`npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13` and a few more text on ERR

Comment: I think you need to use `sudo` to install an npm package globally